# I have multiple drop dropdown under <aura: iteration/>, then how to get selected value of dropdown

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, lighting-web-component

[![In this list the first field is an iteration on my apps fields and then salesforce object, Sync Direction, and Salesforce Field. **My question is how to get the value of any selected box(arrow) using function**
My controller Function is

```
salesforceObjChange : function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log("Salesforce Object Changed!!");
    alert('dddddddddddddddddd');
    var afList = component.get('v.afList');
    var affiliation = afList[ev.srcElement.id];
    console.log("affiliation", affiliation);
    alert(component.find('salesforceobject').get('v.value') + ' pie is good.');

    /*let avc = component.find("salesforceObject").get("v.value")
    console.log("avcaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"); 
    let a = component.find("salesforceObject");
    console.log("avb", a);
    let a = event.getSource().get("salesforceObject");
    console.log("abc", component.find('salesforceObject').get('v.value'));
    let a =  event.getParam("salesforceObject");
    console.log("Object last", a);*/
    
},
```

and component code is

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.acquireFields}" var="acquireFields" indexVar="acqindex">
      <li class="slds-item" id="{!acquireFields.key}">
       <span class="acquire-fields">{!acquireFields.key}</span>
       <span class="salesforce-object" id="{!acqindex}">
          <lightning:select aura:id="salesforceobject" name="salesforceobject" 
              required="true"onchange="{!c.salesforceObjChange}">
            <option value="">None</option>
            <option value="contact">Contact</option>
            <option value="lead">Lead</option>
          </lightning:select>
        </span>
        <span class="sync-direction">
            <lightning:select name="sync-direction" aura:id="syncDirection" required="true"
                        onchange="{!c.syncDirectionChange}">
                 <option value="">None</option>
                 <option value="salesforceToAcquire">Salesforce -> Acquire</option>
                 <option value="acquireToSalesforce">Acquire -> Salesforce</option>
                 <option value="bidirectional">Bidirectional</option>
             </lightning:select>
         </span>
         <span class="salesforce-fields">
            <lightning:select name="contactSetting" aura:id="contactSetting" required="true" 
                      onchange="{!c.salesforceContactChange}">
                 <option value="" selected= "{!v.contactOptions.key == ''}">None</option>
                 <aura:iteration items="{!v.contactOptions}" var="contactOptions">
                     <option text="{!contactOptions.name}" value="{!contactOptions.key}" 
                          selected="{!contactOptions.selected}"/>
                 </aura:iteration>
              </lightning:select>
           </span>                                                  
         </li>
      </aura:iteration>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAxgO.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAxgO.png)

[image: After that i have save button, in the Onclick event I want all fields to value like]

```
var mappingObject = [{acqFieldsKey: "name", salesforceObject: "contact", syncDirection: "BiDirectional", salesforceFieldsKey: "lastName"}, {...},{...}]
```

[image: Consider as 1st image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be worth creating a new lightning component that represents a row, then add that component for each line. But if you wanted to handle it all in the parent component, here's how I'd do it:

```
<lightning:select name="{!acqindex}" required="true" onchange="{!c.salesforceObjChange}"> ... </lightning:select>
```

The index of the row is stored in the component's name field. Then the controller:

```
let selectComp  = event.getSource();
let selectIdx   = selectComp.get('v.name') * 1; // ensure it's an integer, not a string
let afList      = component.get('v.afList');
var affiliation = afList[selectIdx];
```

Some more documentation on this technique: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_base_events.htm

Comment: value get 
let selectIdx   = selectComp.get('v.value');